# Intuition of TailVaR

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, utility, distribution-tails

As per the actuarial guide I have called the CMP - from Acted - tailVaR is the expected loss in excess of the benchmark value L.
I don't really get that, so I tried splitting the equation into:
$tailVar(X) = $$\int_{-\infty}^{L} (L-x)f(x) dx$$ $. 
I've divided this equation up into 
$\int_{-\infty}^{L} L.f(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^{L} x.f(x) dx = L.P(X<L) - E[X|X<L]$

What does $L.P(X<L)$ mean intuitively, or can someone just explain it through equation format for me?

Comment: $L$ multiplied by the probability of $X$ being less than $L$, what else do you want for “intuition”? TailVar looks like $\mathbb{E}[(L-X)^+]$ where $y^+$ is $\max\{y,0\}$. It is exactly what you say: the expected loss in excess of the benchmark value $L$. What more do you want or what is not clear about this interpretation?

Comment: Also the splitting of the equation is slightly incorrect: $\int_{-\infty}^L xf(x) dx$ is equal to $\mathbb{E}(X\cdot \mathbb{1}_{X< L})$ *not* the conditional expectation of $X$ conditional on $X<L$ as you have written.

Comment: And if the second comment is not clear or if you are not familiar with indicator functions, $\mathbb{1}_A$: you can also rewrite the second term as $\mathbb{E}(X|X<L)\mathbb{P}(X<L)$